# Send an array of Characters as a parameter to a function in C ++

Tags: c++

I have a function that receives two parameters: one input and one input/output, the first is a constant type `string` and the second is a reference to an `array` of `unsigned char` characters, the problem is that when I pass the address of the array, it generates this error when compiling `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

This is the code where I call the function:

```
unsigned char in[20];
string str = "ABCDEF123456";

function(str, &in); //ERROR HERE
```

And this is the function:

```
void function(const std::string &str, unsigned char *&in)
{
    in = new unsigned char[str.length() / 2];

    for (int aux = 0, tam_str = str.length(); aux != tam_str; aux += 2)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << str.substr(aux, 2);

        int valor;
        ss >> valor;

        in[aux / 2] = valor;
    }
}
```

NOTE: The purpose of the function is to convert the content of the variable `str` (hexadecimal values) to the array of characters `in`.

Comment: `in` in your calling code should be a `std::vector<unsigned char>`

Comment: `unsigned char[20]` is not implicitly convertible to `std::vector<unsigned char>&` by any means. Try replacing `in` with `std::vector<unsigned char> in;`

Comment: You'll probably live a more happy life if you just use `std::vector` or `std::array`. *So many* problems you will not have.

Comment: @NoeCano your edits have changed the meaning of the question completely. Please revert the edits or ask a new question.

Comment: @NathanOliver i update the code (i was using other snippet)

Comment: @alterigel i update the code (i was using other snippet)

Comment: Your edit invalidates user2079303's answer.  You might be better off rolling the edit back and asking a new question with the correct code.

Comment: @NoeCano your edits mean that user2079303's answer, which was a good answer to your original question, no longer makes sense. As an aside, I would _strongly_ recommend using `std::vector` over raw arrays and to avoid any pointers whenever possible. It will save you tons of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the argument declaration, and the type of the object that you pass do not match.

Answer for new question:

Like in the old version, you pass a pointer to an array of 20 unsigned char. But the argument type is a reference to a pointer to a unsigned char. That doesn't work.

To call the function, you must have a pointer to an unsigned char:

```
unsigned char* ptr = in;
function(str, ptr);
```

On the other hand, it makes no sense to pass a pointer by reference unless you modify the pointer - which you don't do. So, it might be more sensible to pass a copy of the pointer instead:

```
void function(const std::string &str, unsigned char *in);

function(str, in);
```

---

Old answer:

```
void function(const std::string &str, std::vector<unsigned char> &in)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
unsigned char in[20];
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
function(str, &in); //ERROR HERE
              ^^^
```

The function has been declared to accept a reference to a `std::vector<unsigned char>` object. You attempt to pass an address to an array of 20 unsigned char as the argument. That doesn't work.

To call the function, you need to have a vector object:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> in;
function(str, in);
```

Comment: The OP has updated the Q with their real code and it invalidates this answer.  Not sure what you want to do.

Comment: @NathanOliver I answered the new version as well.